# Show progress bar only if file upload starts

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, progress

I'm using jQuery and Ajax to upload files and I also have a progress bar to display the progress of the upload. Everything is fine except I want this progress bar to appear only if the upload progress starts not when I get validation errors from the Laravel controller. How can I do it?

Here is my code :

```
$('[type="file"]').change(function () {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('video', $(this)[0].files[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/url',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data: formData,
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        xhr: function () {
            var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.upload.addEventListener('loadstart', function () {
                $('#progressbar').fadeIn(100);
            });
            xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (e) {
                if (e.lengthComputable) {
                    var percentageComplete = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
                    $('#progressbar span').css('width', percentageComplete + '%');
                }
            });
            return xhr;
        },
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.status == 'error') {
                $(this).parent().append('<p class="text-danger" role="alert">' + response.message + '</p>');
            } else {
                //
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the logic which displays the progress bar in to the `progress` handler, based on the `loaded` value being higher than `0`:

```js
var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
  if (e.lengthComputable) {
    if (e.loaded)
      $('#progressbar').fadeIn(100);

    var percentageComplete = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
    $('#progressbar span').css('width', percentageComplete + '%');
  }
});
```

Comment: How about the situation where I select a file other than a video file and `e.loaded` shows a number greater than 0? In this situation I also get the error (from controller) that says file should be video type.

Comment: Good point. If you're validating on the server side, which is a good thing to be doing, then I believe you cannot make the progress bar behave as you're asking. This is because some data has to be transferred in order for the server to validate the content type, MIME type etc. This data transfer will always be detected by the XHR object regardless of whether or not the server was happy to accept the request. All you could do in that case is hide the progress bar again when the error occurs.